# confusion over how duration vs. periods work in lubridate with month addition

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Here is what I think is a possible bug:

```
require(lubridate)
d = as.Date("1994-03-31")
> d + months(1)
  [1] "1994-05-01"
```

My understanding is that this should return the end of month 4 of year 1994.  Please advise if this is indeed a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is a documented feature.  <s>It is definitely not a bug in `lubridate` 
 as `months` and `as.Date` are both `base` package functions.</s> . (Edit. `months.numeric` and `months.integer` are both non-visible functions from the `lubridate` package.

However, `luibridate` does have an answer!

It is doing exactly as specified in the help file for `%m+%` (which is part of the `lubridate` package.)

> Adding months frustrates basic arithmetic because consecutive months have different lengths. With other elements, it is helpful for arithmetic to perform automatic roll over. For example, 12:00:00 + 61 seconds becomes 12:01:01. However, people often prefer that this behavior NOT occur with months. For example, we sometimes want January 31 + 1 month = February 28 and not March 3. months(n) always returns a date in the nth month after Date. If the new date would usually spill over into the n + 1th month, month. Date nth month before Date.

The function `%m+%` is designed to ensure the feature you want, ensuring that the month isn't rolled over

```
d %m+% months(1)

## [1] "1994-04-30"
```

Note that  this feature was introduced in [version 1.2.0](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/NEWS), and thus is not documented in http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i03/paper, as this was written prior to the implementation

Also note that you could also use  `duration(1, 'months')`

```
 d + duration(1, 'months')
 ## [1] "1994-04-30"
```

Comment: The way `duration` and `period` handle the fluid nature of the length of `months` and `minutes` *is* rather confusing. I might wait for @hadley (or someone else) to add a definitive answer. I've read the help for `period` and `duration`, and neither want to claim they will work flawlessly for months (although in this example, `duration ` appears to work

Comment: great explanation, thank you. it is a bit confusing as to what `duration` and `period` actually do in light of this example.  will see if @hadley has a chance to comment and explain.

Comment: @Alex, I'd suggest editing the title, perhaps `confusion over how month addition works with lubridate`

Comment: should i unaccept the answer so he sees this question as open or will be see it regardless?

Comment: Might be an idea, I won't be offended!

Comment: ok - i will do this. i will reaccept once he looks at it. very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Given the excerpt from the documentation, I'm not sure what you want me to say. But date time math is complex, and it's not obvious that one month after "1994-03-31" should be "1994-03-30". What is one month after "2000-01-28", "2000-01-29" and "2001-01-30"? (Do you remember the full leap year rules?). Should `x + days(1) + months(1)` be different to `x + months(1) + days(1)`

Comment: @hadley: could you explain the difference is between duration and periods? given the example above it is completely unclear

Comment: A duration is always measured in seconds, so a duration of month is an approximation, as you see when you run `duration(1, 'months')` - it's 2628000s, 1/12 of a year.  It's only luck that it works in this case. A period is some thing meaningful to humans.

Comment: @hadley: got it, `duration` makes sense. what about `period`? to your previous question: 1 month after 2000-01-28 is the last date of 2000-02-XX in my mind if the point of `period` is to work with a human notion of time. if it's not, then i don't see the point of having `period` at all. could you explain?

Comment: @Alex see my previous comment. It's impossible to satisfy everyone's intuition for time.

Comment: @hadley: completely understand. however, if everybody's idea of a `period` is different.. then what is it actually in lubridate? this is what makes no sense to me. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Alex it's described in the paper, in the documentation and in my previous comment. I'm not sure what else I can tell you :/